# Can I use additional pins from Google Coral Dev Board as GPIO?

Tags: gpio, tpu

It seems that only 8 pins from the 40-pin header can be used as GPIO on Google Coral Dev board.

We want to use a peripheral (compatible with Raspberry pi 4.0) that needs 14 pins for GPIO (adafruit RGB hat matrix).

Is is possible to use/reconfigure some of the remaining pins on the header as GPIO? (i.e. UART, I2C, SPI)

Comment: You may always add I²C GPIO expander, such as PCA9535 or compatible (gives you 16 GPIOs). Otherwise it probably possible if those pins are not used for anything else, in such case you need to configure a pin control properly.

Comment: Thanks @0andriy  . That is very helpful suggestion.